# SQL server 2005 numeric precision loss

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, type-conversion, casting, floating-accuracy

Debugging some finance-related SQL code found a strange issue with numeric(24,8) mathematics precision.

Running the following query on your MSSQL you would get A + B * C expression result to be 0.123457

SELECT A,
       B,
       C,
       A + B * C
FROM
(
SELECT CAST(0.12345678 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS A,
       CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS B,
       CAST(500 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS C
) T

So we have lost 2 significant symbols. Trying to get this fixed in different ways i got that conversion of the intermediate multiplication result (which is Zero!) to numeric (24,8) would work fine.

And finally a have a solution. But still I hace a question - why MSSQL behaves in this way and which type conversions actually occured in my sample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as addition of the float type is inaccurate, multiplication of the decimal types can be inaccurate (or cause inaccuracy) if you exceed the precision. See [Data Type Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530%28SQL.90%29.aspx#_decimal) and [decimal and numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Since you multiplied `NUMERIC(24,8)` and `NUMERIC(24,8)`, and SQL Server will only check the type not the content, it probably will try to save the potential 16 non-decimal digits (24 - 8) when it can't save all 48 digits of precision (max is 38). Combine two of them, you get 32 non-decimal digits, which leaves you with only 6  decimal digits (38 - 32).

Thus the original query

```
SELECT A, B, C, A + B * C
FROM ( SELECT CAST(0.12345678 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS A,
  CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS B,
  CAST(500 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS C ) T
```

reduces to

```
SELECT A, B, C, A + D
FROM ( SELECT CAST(0.12345678 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS A,
  CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS B,
  CAST(500 AS NUMERIC(24,8)) AS C,
  CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(38,6)) AS D ) T
```

Again, between `NUMERIC(24,8)` and `NUMERIC(38,6)`, SQL Server will try to save the potential 32 digits of non-decimals, so `A + D` reduces to

```
SELECT CAST(0.12345678 AS NUMERIC(38,6))
```

which gives you `0.123457` after rounding.

Comment: do you meant NUMERIC(32,6)) ?? If the sum must be 38

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Please read the links and understand what both numbers mean.

Comment: You say that when multiplying two numeric (24,8) the server will try to save 16 bits and produce a  (32,6) , how does it become a 38,6? Thanks

Comment: @Edmondo1984 In `NUMERIC(p, s)`, `p` stands for precision the _total_ number of digits. So in `NUMERIC(24, 8)` there are 16 digits of non-decimals. No bits. Again, please read the link to the msdn docs.

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic pointed out by [eed3si9n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126401/sql-server-2005-numeric-precision-loss#126473) and what you said in your question it seems that the best approach when doing mathematics operations is to extract them into a function and additionally to specify precision after each operation,

It this case the function could look something like:

```
create function dbo.myMath(@a as numeric(24,8), @b as numeric(24,8), @c as numeric(24,8))
returns  numeric(24,8)
as
begin 
    declare @d as numeric(24,8)
    set @d = @b* @c
    return @a + @d
end
```

Comment: That approach may not solve the issue of SQL Server chopping off the decimal parts. To save the decimal parts, it may be necessary to cast to @a and @b into double.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it in mind when working on some precision maths in SQL, So far I have not need to use it but it is good to now that there may be some issues to consider

Answer (score 0):

Despite what it says on [Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). I believe it is also applying a minimum 'scale' (number of decimal places) of 6 to the resulting NUMERIC type for multiplication the same as it does for division etc.