# Unit Conversion precision issue

Tags: sql, angularjs, sql-server, math, asp.net-web-api2

Seeking an solution to the following problem.

In our application we were having an functionality of converting the units as per user selection. e.g . Convert kg to lbs or vice versa based on unit selection by user.

1. We have a screen where in user can select the unit in which he is providing the value e.g Kg or lbs
2. We have a table which contains all the formulas for the predefined unit which our system supports e.g **1Kg = 2.20462lbs** like so
3. We fetch the formula from the database and calculate / evaluate the formula with actual values as provided by the user.
4. Since , user have ability to see any units as per his/her choice. we decided to save the value which user provided on screen in standard unit only in our database for easier maintainablity . in this case let's say we have decided to save in kg only database however , user may have selected 'lbs' on screen , but while saving we do convert the 'lbs' to 'kg' and then we will save to database
5. while reading from database we do convert to 'lbs' if user intended to see in 'lbs' on screen

Hope till now the implementaton is clear , now the problem to above solution is

1. Let's assume user have selected value '1' as  'lbs' and saved it
2. In database we will save in 'kg' so value of '1' is saved as **2.20462** in database
3. while reading again we will do convert to show in 'lbs' now we get value as **0.999998**. this is expected due to precision in formula
4. But user asking to atleast show the same value what he as entered , in this case '1' but we have to do calculation to convert it back to 'lbs' since we are saving in 'kg' in database

I am seeking an solution to this problem what could be better solution with minimal changes.

Table Definition

```
Id | UnitConversion
1  |   100
2  |   200
3  |   30
```

Our application is developed on 
Angularjs, webapi and sql server

Comment: What is the table column definition?  Where the conversion takes place (Angular, DB, etc)?

Comment: Conversion takes place at client side using directive of Angularjs and saved the conversion value in database in single column without any unit Id as we save value in 'Kg' only. Have updated the table definition in my post. Hope this helps

Comment: What's `UnitConversion` definition (float, double, number)?

Comment: Its numeric in sql server

Comment: I suggest that you increase the precision on your `UnitConversion` column, probably to `float(53)`. And establish a supported precision on the UI, so you can properly round values.

Comment: @wdosanjos float is NOT appropriate it is an approximate data type with precision problems for situations like this. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Matt why not? please elaborate.  His system does not store the value entered by the user, but the converted value which is not precise due to math precision issues.  `number` can cause issues especially, when the converted values are between 1 and -1.

Comment: @wdosanjos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199371/sql-server-precision-crazyness http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126401/sql-server-2005-numeric-precision-loss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701710/sql-server-rounding-error-giving-different-values Float is an approximation and has rounding issues, multiplications, sum issues granted typically with larger data sets for the suming.  But If the OP is already having rounding issue with how they are storing the value, introducing a datatype that is approximate should exasperate those issues not improve them.

Comment: @Matt I don't think those posts apply in this case.  Let's say that the converted value (to be stored) is 0.0000220462, if it is to be stored as `decimal(20,5)` there will be a huge loss of precision.

Comment: Unless you will centrally use the converted information for a global purpose you may want to reconsider storing the value how the user inputs and a foreign key to the unit of measure.  That way no conversion is ever necessary and you always preserve the users intent  also less code upon retrieving values.  Also when you retrieve the values it is likely that having consistent rounding would combat most of this issue 1 and .99998 are the same thing once your round, and you can increase the precision of your numeric column to hold 10+ decimal points to increase accuracy

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is a stripped down version of my conversion utility.  Just showing MASS here.   By storing the conversion factors as varchar, precision is at the individual record level.

```
Declare @Map table (MapType varchar(50),MapName varchar(50),MapValue varchar(50))
Insert Into @Map values
('Mass','tonnes (metric)','1000'),
('Mass','tons (US)'      ,'907.18474'),
('Mass','tons (UK)'      ,'1016.0469088'),
('Mass','stones'         ,'6.35029318'),
('Mass','slugs(g-pounds)','14.593903'),
('Mass','Solar masses'   ,'1.989e30'),
('Mass','pounds (troy)'  ,'0.3732417216'),
('Mass','pounds'         ,'0.45359237'),
('Mass','picograms'      ,'1e-15'),
('Mass','ounces'         ,'0.028349523'),
('Mass','ounces (troy)'  ,'0.0311034768'),
('Mass','nanograms'      ,'1e-12'),
('Mass','milligrams'     ,'1e-6'),
('Mass','micrograms'     ,'1e-9'),
('Mass','megatonnes'     ,'1e9'),
('Mass','kilotonnes'     ,'1e6'),
('Mass','kilograms'      ,'1'),               --- << Base
('Mass','hundredweights' ,'50.80234544'),
('Mass','hectograms'     ,'0.1'),
('Mass','grams'          ,'1e-3'),
('Mass','grains'         ,'0.00006479891'),
('Mass','femtograms'     ,'1e-18'),
('Mass','Earth masses'   ,'5.980e24'),
('Mass','decagrams'      ,'0.01'),
('Mass','cental'         ,'45.359237'),
('Mass','carats (metric)','0.0002')

Declare @Value float      = 1
Declare @From  varchar(50)= 'kilograms'
Declare @To    varchar(50)= 'pounds'

Select @Value * Max(IIF(MapName=@From,cast(MapValue as float),null))  / Max(IIF(MapName=@To,cast(MapValue as float),null)) 
 From  @Map 
 Where MapName in(@From,@To)
```

Returns

```
2.20462262184878
```

Answer (score 0):

At Sql server side choose a finer scale then that you need to return to a client. For example, if you need 5 digits to the right of the decimal point, set scale to 7 for DB column

```
declare @n decimal(20,5) = 2.20462;

declare @t table (
      m decimal(20,7)
);

insert @t(m) values 
   (1./@n), 
  (10./@n), 
 (1000./@n);

select cast(m*@n as decimal(20,5)) as r 
from @t;
```

Note "Decimal and numeric are synonyms and can be used interchangeably." [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: would be good to note "Decimal and numeric are synonyms and can be used interchangeably."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx so the OP can just make sure the precision and scale of numeric are large enough without having to change to decimal.