# Sql server gives different result for the same mathematical calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Step1**

Query :

```
SELECT
(ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(38, 14), '123456789.34554563453524'), 0) 
 * 
ISNULL(try_convert(NUMERIC(38, 14), '456789876.34556345345353'), 0))/100.0
```

Result :

```
563938115391720.660302
```

**Step2**

The above query I have modified to :

```
SELECT (123456789.34554563453524 * 456789876.34556345345353) / 100.0
```

But the result is :

```
563938115391720.660302253145411988
```

Here, the Step1 query result has truncated the decimals at some point.

How to re-write it to get the exact number (**563938115391720.660302253145411988**) I got for Step2 query.

Comment: I won't mark as duplicate, but I think [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126401/sql-server-2005-numeric-precision-loss) might explain your observations.  There are only a max of 48 digits of precision available, and your products may be exceeding this limit.  Rounding error with floating point is a known problem in all programming languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why precision is decreasing when multiply sum to other number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313598/why-precision-is-decreasing-when-multiply-sum-to-other-number)

Comment: The chance that you actually *need* this precision is close to zero. It may actually be zero if you round it down. Note that SQL Server has no arbitrary-precision data types, so no matter that you do, there will *always* be calculations where you lose precision, even if *this one* happens to be possible. If you just want the difference explained, that's fine, but don't mislead yourself into thinking you can have exact results in all cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The numbers are all decimal, not float. It's how SQL Server interprets literals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql

Comment: @gbn You know more about SQL Server than I do, but I would have been shocked if the answer weren't a precision thing...this sort of question appears in the Java tag at least every few days :-)

Comment: This link does explain why it is truncated to 6 decimal places:   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/03/29/multiplication-and-division-with-numerics/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, in this case it is the precision before the decimal point the bollixes it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen assuming that unconverted decimal values like "100.1" are implicitly converted to float by SQL Server, I tried a variation of OP's first query where I converted 100.0 to numeric, and it yielded the same result.   I even removed the ISNULL and the division by 100.0, and it still truncated the decimal, so I considered this proof that float-precision was not a factor.

Comment: @TabAlleman the numbers are all decimal in SQL Server. No "E" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly as predicted by decimal precision.
See [T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925)

[Numbers with decimal points are interpreted as NUMERIC in SQL Server to the exact precision shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql). Not float. In this case `decimal (23, 14)`

In the first example they are `decimal (38, 14)`

Same result when using the **same** precision with explicit CONVERTs to the same datatype

```
SELECT
(ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(23, 14), '123456789.34554563453524'), 0) 
 * 
ISNULL(try_convert(NUMERIC(23, 14), '456789876.34556345345353'), 0))/100.0

563938115391720.660302253145411988
```

Note, the `100.0` is `decimal(4,1)` in this case too

Final words: [this is long division that used to be taught at school](http://www.mathsteacher.com.au/year7/ch06_decimals/13_div_dec/dec.htm) after some precision changes because of the 38/23 difference in the multiplication